# How to take a threshold of only a part of the image with OTSU thresholding?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OTSU threshold on a dilated and eroded image as shown below:

```
k = np.ones((5,5),np.float32)/1
        d = cv2.dilate(self.img, k, iterations=10)
        e = cv2.erode(d, k, iterations=10)
        self.thresh = cv2.threshold(e, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

This is the eroded  and dilated image, and the one that gets thresholded:

[image]

I only want the circular bright region in the middle to be obtained from thresholding, but instead I'm getting this result:

[image]

How do I go about thresholding such that I only get the circular region in the middle, which also seems like the brightest (visually) part of the image?

Note: To avoid playing around with different values, I want to stick to OTSU thresholding, but I'm open to ideas.

Comment: The problem is, I want to use *only* OTSU threshold because the lower threshold varies a LOT.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you elaborate please?

Comment: If I use just binary threshold, I will have to set a lower threshold value -- which varies a lot from image to image.

Comment: OTSU is a binary threshold. It just automatically computes the threshold value. What you're doing now is correct, just probably not what you need.

Comment: Yeah, I meant I need the threshold value automatically computed. But if I use just binary threshold, that won't be the case.

Comment: Right now you _are_ computing the threshold value automatically... Are you looking for something like [this](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/multithresh.html), instead?

Comment: I'm calculating it automatically, I know that. I want to keep it that way, while also obtaining the threshold I want. I basically want to get rid of the extension towards the top.

Comment: you have tried many different ways: is this a constant picture that you can somehow fine tune? otherwise playing with the parameters is a waste of time - the 10 iterations you are trying here W'ONT work elsewhere - thats a kid's play

Comment: @gpasch, What? The first picture you're seeing is eroded and dilated by 10 iterations. I'm not sure what you're saying. What's a kid's play? Learning by experimenting? At least be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Dilate and Erode filters to this image, but in another order: Erode first and then Dialte. It will  suppress bright areas from upper side of the image and threshold method will provide better result

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try a gradient based approach. Below I've used the morphological gradient. I apply Otsu thresholding to this gradient image, followed by a similar amount of morphological closing (10 iterations), then take the morphological gradient of the resulting image.

Now the regions are easy to detect. You can filter the circular region from the contours, for example, using an area based approach: using bounding box dimensions of the contour, you can get an estimate of the radius, then compare the calculated area to the contour area.

Don't know how generic this approach would be for your collection.

**Gradient image: intensity values scaled for visualization**

[image: grad]

**Binarized gradient image**

[image: bw]

**Closed image**

[image: closed]

**Gradient**

[image: cont]

```
im = cv2.imread('LDxOj.jpg', 0)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3, 3))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(im, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
_, bw = cv2.threshold(morph, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
morph2 = cv2.morphologyEx(bw, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel, anchor = (-1, -1), iterations = 10)
morph3 = cv2.morphologyEx(morph2, cv2.MORPH_GRADIENT, kernel)
```